# Can I run custom queries using ObjCMongoDB

Tags: mongodb, objcmongodb

I want to run custom queries on mongoDB from an iOS application. I’m using ObjCMongoDB. How can I implement the queries like

db.logs.find()

Comment: possible duplicate of [ObjCMongoDB db.collection.find()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644095/objcmongodb-db-collection-find)

Comment: That means no support for find query at the moment.

Comment: So what’s the possibility to use multiple search conditions using MongoPredicate.

Comment: Yes, MongoPredicate has factory methods to create boolean predicates you can combine with other predicates.