# ObjCMongoDB db.collection.find()

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, objcmongodb

I want to implement complex queries on mongoDB in my iOS app. I’m using ObjCMongoDB and it’s working  perfectly. I’m able to implement the count query on the database, please see the following code

```
commandDict = @{@"count": @"logs",@"query":@{@"detector":@"kaspersky"}};
commandDictdata = [dbConn runCommandWithDictionary:commandDict onDatabaseName:@"logdb" error:&error];
```

I’m trying to implement db.collection.find() but having troubles. Can anyone explain me how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`-runCommandWithDictionary` can't be used to perform the equivalent of `db.collection.find()`.

You have to use MongoKeyedPredicate. At present the library doesn't have a way to pass a dictionary to `mongo_find`.

I'm the author of the library. A pull request would be welcome.